# Tableau - bigquery display filter

Tags: data-visualization, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have dataset in big-query (Rows : 4,703,154,740 & size : 978 GB). Tableau Desktop running on Windows box with config :

OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack 1
Processor : Intel Xeon ES620 2.40 GHz (2 Processors)
Installed Ram : 128 GB (32 G Usable)
System Type : 64 Bits

How do I create a display filter, because I am getting out of memory error when I try to create report ?

Comment: How are you connecting to BigQuery from Tableau? Are you using a live connection, or pulling your data into memory ("Import all data")?

Comment: Is it possible for you to do a custom SQL instead of connecting directly to the whole table (in order to reduce the amount of data)? Also, how many different values do you have in the filter that you tried to build?

Comment: @DavidMSmith I am using live connection

Comment: Is the error coming from bigquery (query is failing) or tableau? If bq then you might look in your query history, find the query that's causing problems, and post it here.

Comment: @DavidMSmith Its from Tableau